# Default data in Webapp?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

how can I setup default data in a webapp? Eg default users: admin, test, etc.

I first thought of defining a static section in of of my session-beans, but that would still cause a new creation of users for every session. Which is not suitable.

How can I do else?

ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using hibernate (I'll assume you are from the question tags), then all you need is to have an file called *import.sql* in your classpath, and hibernate will automatically execute it if you have the *hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto* property set to *create* or *create-drop*.  Have a look at this link:

http://relation.to/Bloggers/RotterdamJBugAndHibernatesImportsql#H-ImportsqlEasilyImportDataInYourUnitTests

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to put in your webapp's configuration section, there it will be loaded and read only once through the following steps :
an xml file of your data, just put it on your class path and read it by using java propery which will get an input stream of your class loader path